# Using :not() selector to style <a> elements not inside <p> elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to style any `<a>` in my website that doesn't appear inside a `<p>` to look more like a button.

I have been looking at the `:not()` selector and think this should work to select them:

```
:not(p) a {}
```

However doesn't seem to work in the way I expect. I have a codepen here as an example

https://codepen.io/pummra/pen/eYJoNqd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can address the *direct* children in the selector using `>` between the two tags:

```
:not(p) > a
```

Otherwise that selector (without the `>`) would almost always apply, since an `a` tag inside a `p` tag is for example also a (not direct) child of the `body` tag.

Applied to your Codepen example:

```css
a {
  color: #00f;
}

:not(p) > a {
    background-color: #1779ba;
    color: #fefefe;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    padding: 0.85em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>An interesting article</h1>
  <p>This is an interesting article about something. There will be a bunch of copy here. Some of it might even have a <a href="http://www.google.com">link in</a>. The links in the copy would look like normal links. The links outside of the paragraph should look like buttons.</p>
  <a href="#">Read more about this</a>
</div>
```